# How to make dynamic github badges, that is, images in README which change state?

Tags: github, go, badge

How do you add a "badge" in GitHub README so that it is dynamic? By "badge", I mean [image]

The question is even if one puts a URL in GitHub README which maps to a server returning an svg/png, how does it update automatically on GitHub README page?

As an example if you visit the [link](https://github-shields.com/github/maddyonline/copyshields/issues/1.svg)
, you'd see the updated status of the issue (which is closed), but my GitHub [README page](https://github.com/maddyonline/copyshields) still shows outdated badge, that is, shows the issue being open.

What is an example server code (say in golang) which can render github badges dynamically?

Comment: This problem can still be solved using `no cache` and proper `Etag` header I believe because services like `travis ci` have proper implementation for this

Answer (score 3):

It's just an image at a URL. It's up to the server [(your example looks like Jenkins)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin) to decide what image to provide.

Comment: Yes, but look at the image that this link provides: https://github-shields.com/github/maddyonline/copyshields/issues/1.svg, but the github page (https://github.com/maddyonline/copyshields)  using this link  in README is not getting updated automatically with the image that this url outputs.

Comment: The image in the README **is** updated. It's likely just browser caching that you're seeing. http://i.stack.imgur.com/oxBXF.png