# Implementing GitHub Badges in Golang

Tags: github, go, cache-control

I have asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121981/how-to-make-dynamic-github-badges-that-is-images-in-readme-which-change-state) and didn't receive satisfactory answer, so this time I'd try to be more specific.

I would like to implement a server in golang which outputs dynamic status updates in the form of svg. (Think "Build Passing/Failing" GitHub Badges.) The purpose is that one should be able to embed a link to the server's address in GitHub Readme and the Readme should update automatically depending on the server state.

Here's the golang code that I came up with but it doesn't seem to work with GitHub aggressive caching. Do I need to add more Cache-Control headers? Do I need to add ETag?

I'm using the following to embed the image in GitHub Readme.

```
[![Mine](http://58dcd0b5.ngrok.com/view)]()
```

Ideally, I would like to see the GitHub Readme change the image every time I load it -- flipping between the two images "correct"/"wrong". (This is just a proof of concept.)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    _ "time"
)
var mymap map[string][]byte

var state bool = false


func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("State %v", state)
    state = !state
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    if state {
        w.Write(mymap["correct"])
    } else {
        w.Write(mymap["wrong"])
    }
}

func main() {
    mymap = make(map[string][]byte)
    mymap["correct"] = []byte(`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="104" height="20"><linearGradient id="b" x2="0" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bbb" stop-opacity=".1"/><stop offset="1" stop-opacity=".1"/></linearGradient><mask id="a"><rect width="104" height="20" rx="3" fill="#fff"/></mask><g mask="url(#a)"><path fill="#555" d="M0 0h54v20H0z"/><path fill="#4c1" d="M54 0h50v20H54z"/><path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 0h104v20H0z"/></g><g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11"><text x="28" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">solution</text><text x="28" y="14">solution</text><text x="78" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">correct</text><text x="78" y="14">correct</text></g></svg>`)
    mymap["wrong"] = []byte(`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="99" height="20"><linearGradient id="b" x2="0" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bbb" stop-opacity=".1"/><stop offset="1" stop-opacity=".1"/></linearGradient><mask id="a"><rect width="99" height="20" rx="3" fill="#fff"/></mask><g mask="url(#a)"><path fill="#555" d="M0 0h54v20H0z"/><path fill="#e05d44" d="M54 0h45v20H54z"/><path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 0h99v20H0z"/></g><g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11"><text x="28" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">solution</text><text x="28" y="14">solution</text><text x="75.5" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">wrong</text><text x="75.5" y="14">wrong</text></g></svg>`)

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/view", viewHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8085", mux)
}
```

Comment: Check out http://shields.io and see how they are serving their images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this commit to shields.io server](https://github.com/badges/shields/commit/f778b9f4f3dce86a97e04301c93bcf2e72b5013a), I made the following changes to the above code and it works now.

```
w.Header().Set("Date", date)
w.Header().Set("Expires", date)
```

For completeness (and in case someone wants to try it out), here's the complete code. (Also on [GitHub](https://github.com/maddyonline/badges).)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var mymap map[string][]byte

var state bool = false

func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    date := time.Now().Format(http.TimeFormat)
    log.Printf("%v", date)
    log.Printf("State %v", state)
    state = !state
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    w.Header().Set("Date", date)
    w.Header().Set("Expires", date)
    if state {
        w.Write(mymap["correct"])
    } else {
        w.Write(mymap["wrong"])
    }
}

func main() {
    mymap = make(map[string][]byte)
    mymap["correct"] = []byte(`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="104" height="20"><linearGradient id="b" x2="0" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bbb" stop-opacity=".1"/><stop offset="1" stop-opacity=".1"/></linearGradient><mask id="a"><rect width="104" height="20" rx="3" fill="#fff"/></mask><g mask="url(#a)"><path fill="#555" d="M0 0h54v20H0z"/><path fill="#4c1" d="M54 0h50v20H54z"/><path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 0h104v20H0z"/></g><g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11"><text x="28" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">solution</text><text x="28" y="14">solution</text><text x="78" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">correct</text><text x="78" y="14">correct</text></g></svg>`)
    mymap["wrong"] = []byte(`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="99" height="20"><linearGradient id="b" x2="0" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bbb" stop-opacity=".1"/><stop offset="1" stop-opacity=".1"/></linearGradient><mask id="a"><rect width="99" height="20" rx="3" fill="#fff"/></mask><g mask="url(#a)"><path fill="#555" d="M0 0h54v20H0z"/><path fill="#e05d44" d="M54 0h45v20H54z"/><path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 0h99v20H0z"/></g><g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11"><text x="28" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">solution</text><text x="28" y="14">solution</text><text x="75.5" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">wrong</text><text x="75.5" y="14">wrong</text></g></svg>`)

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/view", viewHandler)
    log.Println("Server started. Listening on 8085...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8085", mux)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what travis are serving for their images:

```
Age:0
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 30 Mar 2015 07:49:10 GMT
ETag:"88e168c2d5cdb30ee9af739765e78e4d"
Expires:Mon, 30 Mar 2015 07:49:10 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=48
Last-Modified:Wed, 07 Jan 2015 11:26:53 GMT
Timing-Allow-Origin:https://github.com
X-Timer:S1427701750.146025,VS0,VE156
```

It might be a good start to try these and see what works.

Comment: OP: Of course don't blindly copy headers like "ETag" from another source. Ideally, read up on caching and how that is controlled via headers so you don't do something silly/wasteful like prevent all caching for something that only rarely changes or can only change once in some interval.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Github issue about it : https://github.com/github/markup/issues/224

> Assets must include Cache-Control: no-cache and ETag headers. If a
>   badge is not updating, then it means they are not properly setting
>   these headers.

and

> The assets may also need to include either an ETag or Expires header.
>   [Fastly's docs on Cache-Control](https://fastly.zendesk.com/entries/23358013-Intro-to-Caching-and-CDNs) say that no-cache means "re-validate
>   before serving this content", but it doesn't specify what it does to
>   "re-validate". I'm guessing it is re-validating, but there's no
>   indication that the asset has changed, so it continues to serves the
>   cached asset.
>
> An ETag would be the biggest win, since it would guarantee that the
>   cache gets refreshed when it changes, but still saves bandwidth.